# Caps Lock Does Not Enable Uppercase Emacs

Tags: windows, emacs

I have a disability which forces me to type with only one hand: thus, caps-lock functionality is a must have for me in any text editor. Recently, caps-lock stopped working entirely in my Windows environment, but only with Emacs. `w32-capslock-is-shiftlock` is nil. `w32-enable-caps-lock` is set to `t`. I have no unusual modifications to my `.emacs` file. Any ideas as to what could be the case? My emacs version is 24.3.

Comment: No idea.  But you might like to try "emacs -Q" to see if it's linked to some local customizations, and you might lik to try and think of what changed "recently" that might have caused this change.

Comment: Just the obvious to the extent that it applies -- look in the messages buffer to see if there is any indication of a problem during the load process with any script.  I sometimes find that days can go by where a new message gets unnoticed because it only appears under certain conditions.

Comment: Just another check, have you by chance used `xkeymacs` or modified Windows registry with regard to key bindings? These two are fairly common things to do for Emacs users... Perhaps some other utility that may in some way affect how system interprets key presses?

Comment: You can also just convert the lowercase text to uppercase after it has been typed, while you figure out what happened to your caps lock key. I'd try `emacs -Q` first, however, as @Stefan says.

Comment: I don't know if this could be helpful to you, but I've heard of hard-core emacs users who used foot-pedals for some of the more exotic super-meta-control key combinations.

Comment: @user888379 if they were not so expensive, I would jump on that.

Comment: I have had the same problem, also on 24.3, and windows. Solved by a reboot (of the whole machine). Incidentally this happened at the same time as a windows update (probably a coincidence, updates happen rather often nowadays).

Comment: @Gauthier It is truly unfortunate, I can no longer use emacs on win32 because this happens so frequently. Reboots do fix it, however.

Comment: You can't have an older version of emacs?

Comment: Is still reproducible?

Comment: I am also having this issue on Windows. Thought it could be due to some weird setup (I'm using Emacs Prelude), but this behavior keeps going on even on a bare `emacs -Q` instance.

Comment: I had a similar problem: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53726/emacs-on-windows-randomly-stops-recognizing-the-caps-lock-state; a workaround (press the windows key several times) might work for you.